# Nodemailer connection timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer module to send mail from my nodejs application.
I am getting **Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:465**. Can any one help me in solving this.
Here I am pasting my code.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'Gmail',
auth: {
    user: 'my_mail_id@gmail.com',
    pass: 'my_gmail_password'
}
});

console.log('created');
transporter.sendMail({
from: 'my_mail_id@gmail.com',
  to: 'my_mail_id@gmail.com',
  subject: 'hello world!',
  text: 'hello world!'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be firewall problem. I faced similar problem in Ubuntu (Digital Ocean server). Tried to fix  the issue for 3 days, tried using auth2 also, tried with inactive firewall using ufw inactive command, but no luck. Finally I checked Digital Ocean admin panel and created firewall for the droplet. Problem solved by enabling TCP inbound and outbound in firewall settings.

Comment: for which port?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877246/nodemailer-with-gmail-and-nodejs).

It turns out that in order for Google to authorize a third party server to access your account via SMTP now, you have to enable “Less Secure Apps” on your gmail account, if you want to use username/password ([more info here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)).

So you have two option:

- use OAuth
- make your account less secure

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for replying. I tried second option(less secure).  But still same error.

Comment: Just for checking , I have changed this **nodemailer.createTransport({**  to **nodemailer.createTransport({"SMTP"**. I am getting this error **TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'SMTP'**

Comment: It take some time until new settings is applied. So you can try after an hour. That was my experience at least.

Comment: Also look at this official tutorial for gmail - https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail . You might have issue with captcha also.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. But Still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if should be posting this answer but I've faced the same problem while using GMAIL and the reason behind the error for me was being connected to a vpn. I disabled it and now it works.

I'm using an application password

Answer (score 1):

open port inbound outbound rule 587 or others, whichever you are using on server aws/google etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a SMTP transport object
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: 'Hotmail',
    auth: {
        user: "username",
        pass: "paasweord"
    }
});

console.log('SMTP Configured');

// Message object
  var message = {

  // sender info
  from: 'abc@hotmail.com',

   // Comma separated list of recipients
  to: req.query.to //'aadityashukla9@hotmail.com',

   // Subject of the message
  subject:req.query.subject //'Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔', 

  // plaintext body
   text: req.query.text //'Hello to myself!',

  // HTML body
  /*  html:'<p><b>Hello</b> to myself <img src="cid:note@node"/></p>'+
     '<p>Here\'s a nyan cat for you as an embedded attachment:<br/></p>'*/
  };

  console.log('Sending Mail');
  transport.sendMail(message, function(error){
  if(error){
  console.log('Error occured');
  console.log(error.message);
  return;
  }
   console.log('Message sent successfully!');


//transport.close(); // close the connection pool
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'SMTP'

Comment: I think you are using older version of node.
Please, check official resource for more details: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue today, found this documentation...

https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Had to do a capcha process from the server, by visiting a url while logged into gmail.

Hopefully it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already mentioned reference to the information at  https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/, in my case the Internet Router (Speedport W724V) was still a problem. This keeps a list of all allowed SMTP servers. After I had extended the list accordingly, it worked perfectly. I had to do the same with [smtp.ethereal.email](http://smtp.ethereal.email).

Answer (score 0):

> I was using Linode and after researching a lot, I came across this community post (https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19082/i-just-created-my-first-linode-and-i-cant-send-emails-why). By default, they block the ports even if I set up the firewalls. So, I created a ticket and they resolved the issue

https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/438#issuecomment-1888217441

Answer (score -1):

There are the only reasons of this error:

1. Less Secure Apps: you have to Enable the "Less Secure Apps" from your Gmail account.
2. Use OAuth

Comment: This doesn't affect the connection to actual SMTP servers in any way.

Answer (score -1):

host: host,
secureConnection: false,
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
user: user,
pass: pass
}