# Sending gmail using nodemailer but Connection Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to send gmail using nodemailer.
Here is my code.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '<sender@gmail.com>',
            pass: '<password>'
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: '<sender@gmail.com>',
        to: '<receiver@gmail.com>',
        subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
        text: 'That was easy!'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
```

But I always got this error.

```
{ Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\Work\Web\GatherSense\gather-sense-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:771:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (E:\Work\Web\GatherSense\gather-sense-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:757:20)
    at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (E:\Work\Web\GatherSense\gather-sense-backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:229:22)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

I've spent much time and tried in many ways such as allowing secure less apps and turning off firewalls.
But always get the same error. Please help me and thank you.

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/438 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387451/nodemailer-connection-timeout-error

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But you mean which answer is helpful?

Comment: Ridiculous issue. It's not working in local but working well on the cloud server. I'm fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
import config from '../config/environment';


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: config.email_config.SMTP_HOST,
    port: config.email_config.SMTP_PORT,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    auth: {
        user: config.email_config.SMTP_AUTH_USER,
        pass: config.email_config.SMTP_AUTH_PASS
    }
}));

export function mail(emailObj) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail(emailObj)
            .then(success => {
                if (success) {
                    console.log("Email success:::", success);
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Email Error:::", err);
                reject(err)
            })
    })
}
```