# Nodemailer Not working on digital ocean Ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a bunch of code to sent mail. in my local computer it's working but when I uploaded it digital ocean vps server( running ubuntu 16.04 ) is not working ?

I am using gmail to sending emails.

My Code:

```
const output = `
    <p>This mail is from careerline.io</p>
    <h3>5 digit Account Activation Code</h3>
    <ul>  
        <li>Your Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
    </ul>

`;

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: '**@gmail.com',
        pass: '***'
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});


let mailOptions = {
    from: '"careerline.io" <*****@gmail.com>',
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: 'Account Activation Code', 
    text: 'Active Your Account?', 
    html: output
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }

});
```

Showing This error:

```
Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt4
534-5.7.14 DqB6--W6E37DHGKMSkLESmj9kIoimq8FM3LgEobNKCHtSv2GRbDOLDVRi54tPVjyqNWtEr
534-5.7.14 y8DcZsOftSNngR-DbdXPplrhmBmn1XGeQuaWaU3Yb7iItRZsQ4xx24QUsSuKK-oclhAUek
534-5.7.14 h44QuYY-pTtFsKUtfZyHrg5IxcCP4PXvW8VV5HTtRqa_Rf8dbdTvdCgrqQnzJZXtUi7mp4
534-5.7.14 ZCoioCgToVrhWCB63aSVcOnFYAtp73dIDud8RVJBEJmD9veaQL> Please log in via
534-5.7.14 your web browser and then try again
```

.

Comment: Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580754/mail-for-nodemailer-didnt-work-on-azure-server?rq=1

May be a similar problem. Confirm if on the host you have installed the correct dependencies.

Comment: Its working on my local computer and have the question before I have followed this

Comment: check node versions on both of your systems

Comment: However your host will also need to run npm install to install the dependencies, not just on your local machine. Once all your files have been transferred to the DO server, you need to run npm install via ssh or similar to let the server install any dependencies that are required to handle your packages.

Comment: I have did this @A

Comment: @mehta-rohan bro is it vary for different node version? my server running node 8 lts and local running node 10?

Comment: bro check the version of request module also. there are drastic changes in some request modules.

Comment: ok I checking ....