# NodeMailer Invalid Login

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, server-side, nodemailer

I am new to node.js programming .I am using nodemailer module for sending emails.

```
const nodemailer = require ('nodemailer'),
credentials=require('./credentials.js');
var mailTransport=nodemailer.createTransport({
    service:'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user : credentials.gmail.user,
        pass : credentials.gmail.password,
    }
});
function sendMail(mail_id){
    mailTransport.sendMail({
        from: ' "my name" <myname@gmail.com>',
        to : mail_id,   //user@gmail.com
        subject : 'Hello',
        text: "Hello How do u do ?",
    },function(err,info){
        if(err){
            console.log('Unable to send the mail :'+err.message);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Message response : '+info.response);
        }
    });
}
exports.sendMail=sendMail;
```

This is my program for sending emails to different users. But I am getting **Invalid Login** . I don't have any idea why this is coming . I am new to node.js and server side scripting. 
I am using my gmail username and password for credentials.
Please help me.

Comment: Check if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877246/nodemailer-with-gmail-and-nodejs

Comment: @Raghavan What is smtpConfig ?

Comment: smtpConfig is yet another config file , similar to how you use "credentials" in your code .

Comment: How to get all the fields given in answer ?

Comment: You have to got here https://cloud.google.com/console and get the those from Api's and Auth Section .

Comment: Checkout http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha too. I'm not entirely sure but I think it allows a one time login from supposedly untrusted devices trying to login as you (in this case, nodemailer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you double-check your login credentials? Also did you double-check your "from" adress to match your email?

I used the nodemailer for some tests 3 weeks ago with the gmail example given on the github page and it worked like a charm:

https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

Invalid login indicates mistyped/wrong credentials.

Comment: I got Invalid login when the FROM address was something different then the username.

Answer (score 40):

One reason could be the 'modern security standard' protection from Gmail.

Check you gmail inbox for any new mail having subject "Google Account: sign-in attempt blocked"

If yes, open the mail and click on the link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

set 'Access for less secure apps' to 'Turn on'. Try again, it should be working now.

Comment: thank you! I suddenly ran into this issue, and changing this setting fixed it.

Comment: In my case the issue still existed. Check [Gmail - display unlock captcha](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Comment: Looks like less secure apps is no longer supported.   
Nodemailer GitHub issue on this (https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1424) has the updated steps.

Answer (score 16):

Particularly 2 issues: or you don't have enabled **Less Secure Apps** https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps or you don't have enabled **Display Unlock Captcha** https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, you need to turn on both of them.

Comment: You really need to allow access to the two.. Both less secure app and captacha. The two links above really worked for me.. Thanks. one upvote for u

Answer (score 15):

**U need to Enable Security for Apps :**

|*| If u r using gmail,

```
Use :

    service: 'gmail',

Goto : 

    https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Enable : 

    Allow less secure apps: ON
```

---

|*| If u r using yahoo,

```
Use :

    service: 'yahoo',

Goto : 

    https://login.yahoo.com/account/security

Enable : 

    Allow apps that use less secure sign in
```

---

|*| If u r using Live or Hotmail, No need to enable anything.

```
Use :

    service: 'hotmail',
```

Comment: Says everything you need to know about Microsoft in the last few years

Answer (score 6):

In my case,
turning on less secure apps only was not enough: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

I had to enable display unlock captcha also:  https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

This solved my issue and i was able to send emails using nodemail and gmail.

This thing is not random actually nodemailer community site itself says to perform the second step to enable captcha, if turning on the less secure apps do not work alone. 
https://community.nodemailer.com/using-gmail/

[image]

Above image is taken from the nodemailer article link i have shared.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, i have updated the resource! @DimaKozhevin

Answer (score 2):

Adding this as a separate answer, since the accepted answer no longer works.

Since May 30, 2022, Google no longer supports less secure apps. There is a nodemailer GitHub issue on this (https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1424) with the updated steps:

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
- Enable 2FA
- Create App Password for Email
- Copy that password (16 characters) into the pass parameter in Nodemailer auth.

```
...,
  auth: {
    user: 'yourmail@gmail.com', 
    pass: 'your_new_app_password', 
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a workspace user account you may need to, as an admin:

1. Create a user group
2. Add the user to that group
3. Go to the user group settings and enable unsecure apps under Security so that other groups emails won't be affected
4. If that isn't enough (this worked for me after everything was fine for months with first three steps), go to myaccount.google.com and log in with the specific user email and password, go to Security again and turn on less secure apps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Enable 2FA
3. Create App Password for Email
4. Copy that password (16 characters) into the pass parameter in Nodemailer auth.

Working fine when I followed this steps to proceed the nodemailer.