# How to view SMTP credentials to send mail in node js

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am developing an application in node js, which has functionality of sending email. To do the task I need an SMTP username and password. But I can't find the place where I can get it. I am using the following code to do the operation,

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxx@gmail.com', 
    to: 'yyy@gmail.com', 
    subject: 'Hello ✔', 
    text: 'Hello world ', 
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

So can anybody help me to view SMTP credentials to send an email.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeMailer Invalid Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948516/nodemailer-invalid-login)

Comment: Its ur gmail id and its password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply zeeshan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to enter your credentials in this line of code

`var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');`

Replace `user` with your email username and replace `pass` with your email password. Also, note if you have special character # in your password, then it will not work because it will break it into two pieces. I think will happen with other special characters like %,&,@ too. If you have these special characters in your password I recommend to use this structure:

`var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: true, // use SSL
    port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
        user: "yourUserName@gmail.com",
        pass: "yourPassword"
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set security as "less secure" with your Gmail account