# Sending email works locally but not once deployed?

Tags: email, heroku, meteor, smtp, gmail

I have a meteor app that is using the [email](https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html) and [passwords](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html) packages to handle basic password reset functionality.

On my local machine I set the `MAIL_URL` env variable to:

```
smtps://{user}:{password}@smtp.gmail.com:465
```

and after some fiddling with the associated gmail account (I had to [allow less secure applications](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)) it worked.

My live environment is heroku, so I set the env variable there using:

```
heroku config:set MAIL_URL=smtps://{user}:{password}@smtp.gmail.com:465
```

and then confirmed that it was set using `heroku config`.  But for some reason when I try to reset the password on my production environment, it throws the following error:

> Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: Invalid login:
>   534-5.7.14

I even did a `heroku restart` to be absolutely sure that the env variable was picked up and I still get the error.  What's odd is that this is the same error I was getting before I enabled "Less secure apps".

Can anyone see why this might happen?  Suggestions as to how I might fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the Heroku web on your box in Settings/ Config Vars do you actually see this setting?

I see your issue may be due to not confirming the Captcha... Check this out: [Nodemailer with Gmail and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877246/nodemailer-with-gmail-and-nodejs)

Comment: Disabling CAPTCHA did it.  For anyone else trying to solve this - go to this URL to disable: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha