# how to send Email using node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer, email

i tried nodemailer but its not working. i want to send email to user through my node js website. can anyone please help me to get it done
//code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors you can share?

Comment: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemailer with Gmail and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877246/nodemailer-with-gmail-and-nodejs)

Comment: no, i tried that its not working

Answer (score 1):

In my experience sending emails can be made a lot easier by outsourcing the work to a provider like https://www.mailgun.com, the cost is $0.0008 per email. The reason for this is not only simplicity but deliverability. So many people have sent so many fake and junk emails over the years, emails often end up in spam folders when the server is not set up correctly. Things like adding SPF records to domains can obviously help but in all honesty, I now just use a sending provider.

Comment: This is an important point, especially if your service needs to send e-mails to others than yourself, and deliverability is important.

Comment: No, I do not think so, I used it a few years ago last. They give you an API key so you would need that key connected to an account. It was also free up to 10k emails but that may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The port is important to be `465`.

```js
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  },
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: That means your gmail authentication isn't right. You need to check your email and password to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19877246/8817146