# Nodemailer smtp timeout

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

[SMTP information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksOcE.png)I'm getting this error :-

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 144.76.97.27:25
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1132:16)
```

> {
> errno: -4039,
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '144.76.97.27',
> port: 25,
> command: 'CONN'
> }

my code is:-

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.tusharjoshi.tech",
  port: 25,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: "contact@tusharjoshi.tech", // generated ethereal user
    pass: "mypAssword" // generated ethereal password
  },
  tls: {
    // do not fail on invalid certs
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: "tusharjoshi.tech",
  to: "hellotusharr2318@gmail.com",
  subject: `message from ${req.body.name}`,
  text: `Message recieved from ${req.body.email}: and message is about: ${req.body.message}`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send("error");
  } else {
    console.log("send");
    res.send("success");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check this answer? [nodemailer SMTP server connection issue (Error: connect ETIMEDOUT) but it works for another system not in mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67685873/nodemailer-smtp-server-connection-issue-error-connect-etimedout-but-it-works)