# Express nodemail not sending the email in production

Tags: node.js, express, email, nodemailer

I have the following config in my code:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'user@gmail.com
      pass: 'passwrord'
    }
  })
```

It works on my localhost but not in production - cpanel a2hosting.

This [Nodemailer with Gmail and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877246/nodemailer-with-gmail-and-nodejs) doesn't work for me.