# email not sending ejs file nodemailer Node js

Tags: node.js, ejs, nodemailer

email not sending ejs file nodemailer

imports

```
import fs from 'fs'
import express from 'express'
import Email from "../Model/email.js"
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const route = express.Router()
```

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "Gmail", auth: {user: "example@gmail.com",pass:"B122212"}
});
```

function call on button click from forntend react

```
route.post('/',async(req, res)=>
{
    let output = await ejs.renderFile("./views/mail.ejs", { test: 'Test'})
    let mailOptions={ to : req.body.email, subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
html :output }
```

email function

```
     smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response)=>{
                if(error){
                        console.log(error)
                }else{
                        console.log("Message sent")                       
                    }
                })
            }
})
```

Comment: Have a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877246/nodemailer-with-gmail-and-nodejs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.