# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. In html

Tags: javascript, html, email, smtp

I'm making an SMTP-based mail sender. The code that I entered is -

```html
    <script>
    function sendEmail(){
        Email.send({
            Host : "smtp.gmail.com",
            Username : 'davnit7607@davnitjsr.org',
            Password : "*************",
            To : 'davnit7607@davnitjsr.org',
            From : document.getElementById("email").value,
            Subject : "Contact",
        Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
    }
        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not working giving an error -
`The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at - Fix: Try a different SMTP server: https://elasticemail.com/account#/create-account?r=20b444a2-b3af-4eb8-bae7-911f6097521c`

And-
`Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Envelope FROM 'hi@gmail.com' email address not allowed.`
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrbNy.png)

Comment: Please don't include images of your code. You can paste it in a code block in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors...

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.

1. Are you running on HTTPS?
2. You didn't provide proper authentication. You do realize you need your *real* email address (the `username` attribute; you're using Gmail, so you have to provide your *Gmail* address) and your *real* password to send emails from your account, right? (That includes the `from` field.) Gmail also has some extra complications. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45561692/15359157) on how to send emails from Gmail.

> Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: Envelope FROM 'hi@gmail.com' email address not allowed.

You tried to send an email from "hi@gmail.com". Do you think it will work? Let's pretend your email is `bob@gmail.com`. If what you attempted didn't result in an error, that means that I can send an email from your email without your permission! So no, that rightly shouldn't work.

All else aside, please *don't try to send emails from the client-side*. You realize that if you publish your app everyone can see your email address
*and password*, right?

Comment: I have entered the secret token and moreover I have given the right email

Comment: @Abhinavkumar but I doubt you have access to `hi@gmail.com`? (You tried to send an email from there, but you don't even know its password.) If you meant to send emails from `davnit7607@davnitjsr.org`, you have to change the host field to davnitjsr.org's respective SMTP host, and also, **the `from` field must be identical to the username (in most cases)**.