# swiftmailer Symfony 2.7 not send email

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, email, google-email-settings-api

I'm trying to send a test email in Symfony 2.7.3 with swiftMailer nevertheless it isn't work.
I looked many post even if it isn't work. The regular configuration for this often is:

Controller:

```
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Mensaje de prueba')
            ->setFrom('prueba1@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('prueba2@gmail.com')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'GuiasDocentesAppBundle:FAQ:plantillaEmail.html.twig',
                    array('correoConsultante' => $correoConsultante)
                ),
                'text/html'
            )
        ;
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Parameters.yml:

```
{ parameters: { 
    database_host: 127.0.0.1, 
    database_port: null, 
    database_name: databasename, 
    database_user: databaseuser, 
    database_password: databasepassword, 
    mailer_transport: gmail, 
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com, 
    mailer_user: prueba1@gmail.com, 
    mailer_password: passwordforprueba1, 
    secret: *******************************, 
    database_driver: pdo_mysql, 
    database_path: null } }
```

config_dev.yml && config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
encryption: ssl
auth_mode:  login
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

Actually, I'm in development enviroment but I think it isn't a issue. As you can see, prueba1@gmail.com is the same in controller and parameters.yml. The right account (prueba1@gmail.com) have been configured to work with external app without this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
I hope somebody can help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Also the correct bundle have been added :             new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),

Comment: What is the return value of the send method? Do you have any error in log?

Comment: Return int(1), no log errors. Can copy the code of object message...

Comment: Maybe the issue could be the plataform (cloud 9) could not admit it.

Comment: So Swift Mailer seems to send correctly. Try to comment ```{spool: memory}``` and check your spam folder.

Comment: Now the system throw the next error: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "prueba1@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticators

Comment: Ok, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098781/script-sending-mails-with-gmail-failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server. I think that's your exact situation.

Comment: Thanx, it was the case. In addition to said before, allow access to externals app [link] (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) I needed entered the captcha phrase [link] (https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Thanks so much stuzzo!

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 2.7  i got the same issue in one of my app

Solution was  to spool  emails http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/email/spool.html

And send spooled emails via cron  ( lame solution - but  works for me)