# Sending email using gmail smtp

Tags: smtp, gmail, localhost

I am using Gmail SMTP service on my localhost (apache) and its works better.
But when I was uploaded my website into free hosting the smtp isn't works and I got this error
(Smtp connect failed).
How can i work Gmail smtp on the above free hosting?Thanks

Comment: This may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607828/how-to-use-gmail-as-a-free-smtp-server-and-overcome-captcha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GMail as a free SMTP server and overcome captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607828/how-to-use-gmail-as-a-free-smtp-server-and-overcome-captcha)